# Spinner onItemSelected prevent dismiss

Tags: android

How to prevent dismissing the spinner on a single click on its element? More precisly, after a single click on an element in the spinner I would like to open a second spinner and after choosing an element in the second spinner I would like to have both spinners dismissed.